# using attribute in notify clause of resource chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops

I want to use attribute value in notify clause of resource. I have written below code which will first creates a directory and then copies .zip from cookbook_file to that directory. It gives error for notify clause

```
notifies :create , 'cookbook_file["#{node['INSTALLDIR']}/#{node['INSTALLER']}"]', :immediately
```

```
cookbook_file "#{node['INSTALLDIR']}/#{node['INSTALLER']}" do
    source "installer.zip"
    mode 0755
    owner "no"
    group "admin"
    action :nothing
    notifies :install , 'apt_package[unzip]', :immediately
    notifies :run , 'bash[extract]', :immediately
end

user 'no' do
    comment 'User to run wso2 App Server'
    password 'admin@123'
    home '/home/no'
end

directory node['INSTALLDIR'] do
    owner "no"
    group "admin"
    mode "0755"
    action :create
    notifies :create , 'cookbook_file["#{node['INSTALLDIR']}/#{node['INSTALLER']}"]', :immediately
end

apt_package 'unzip' do
    action :install
end

apt_package 'openjdk-6-jdk' do
    action :install
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is string interpolation (`#{...}`) only works inside double-quotes. Try this:

```
notifies :create, "cookbook_file[#{node['INSTALLDIR']}/#{node['INSTALLER']}]", :immediately
```